# Как выдавать роли через команду в discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, бот, discord.py

Я хочу создать команду, которая будет выглядить вот так: `$give @member @role`.

То ошибка, то не читает, и как назло в интернете на русском сегменте подробно про add_role не рассказывают.

Работую с библиотекой 'Discord.py'

Answer (score 1):

```
@bot.command()
async def give(ctx, member: discord.Member, role: discord.Role)
    await member.add_roles(role)
```

[источник](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=add_roles#discord.Member.add_roles)